# Move data from others user accounts in my user account

Tags: users, data-recovery, accounts, user-data

I had problems with compiz setting and I make multiple accounts, now I want to transfer my information from all deleted users in my current account, some data I can not copy because I am not right to read, I type in terminal "`sudo nautilus`" and I get the permission for read, but the copied data is available only for superusers and I must charge the permissions for each file and each folder. How I can copy the information with out the superuser rights OR how I can charge the permissions for selected folder and all files and folders included in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the permission and also own the permission for the folder to which you want to access.

Following command will help you:

```
sudo chown -R saurav:saurav /home/user
sudo chmod -R 777 /home/user
```

Where `saurav` is the user to which you want to own the files and `/home/user` is the example of the user accounting you want to access.. You can change `saurav` to your user's name and `/home/user` to the user account that that you've created.  You can also use this if you want to access files and folders of multiple users:

```
sudo chown -R saurav:saurav /home/user /home/user2
sudo chmod -R 777 /home/user /home/user2
```

and so on..

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the following, assuming the files you want to copy are inside a folder called "backup" for example, do the following where this folder resides:

```
 sudo chmod 777 backup -R
```

Where chmod 777 will give Read, Write and Executable permissions to all files inside this folder to all users in this PC, saving you from having the problem you just mentioned. The -R at the end will make sure all files, sub-directories, in a recursive way will get the permission change.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, there is no way to gain access to that data without elevated permissions.  If you have sudo (I am assuming you do since you ran sudo nautilus) or root access it is quick and easy as the other two posts have mentioned.

Without elevated permissions, I don't know of any "right" way (meaning without breaking in and changing the root password) to get the data.  Nautilus is just the file manager and will not change the set perms.